# Determine parameters of a distribution from its expected value and variance

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

I'm struggling about a simple task that ask to recover the parameter $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of a lognormal distribution from its expected value $\mathbb{E}${X} and variance Var{X}.

I know that when the sample is relatively large, the sample mean is approximately the population mean $\mu$.

By the way, in this case, all that is given is the expected value which I suppose to be equal to the population mean. Same case for the population variance.

Am I losing some concept behind this?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) you can find expressions for mean and variance, enabling you to find $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: Thank you. What I was trying to understand is perhaps something conceptual. For instance, If I have the expected value $\mathbb{E}${X} equal to 3 and the Var{X} equal to 4, can I obtain the parameters of the distribution simply equating the formulas for the mean and the variance in your link to those values?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct route.